# Fast way to access Mat from Opencv on Android?

Tags: android, opencv

I need to modify/access my mat on Android, but it is really really slow (it took about 2 minutes to run on a 3500*100 mat).

I need to set some value to 0, but not all, and I am using this line to modify it.

```
this.getMyMat().put(i, j, 0);
```

Any idea to get it a bit faster ? My code in C++ takes at least 50 times less time to run, doing this way :

```
((myMat.data + myMat.step*row))[j] = 0
```

Comment: What criterion are you using to determine if a pixel should be `0`? It's very likely that OpenCV has a built-in function to do that, depending on the criterion you use.

Comment: For exemple, I want to put 0 on a complete row, or a groupe of rows. (but also for cols, so I really need to keep my 2D shape of my mat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rowRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#rowRange%28int,%20int%29) or [`colRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#colRange%28int,%20int%29) to extract the submatrix you wish to be zeroed out, and call [`setTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#setTo%28org.opencv.core.Scalar%29) to actually fill in the values. This will be faster than iterating pixel-by-pixel.

```
Mat rows = this.getMyMat().rowRange(0,3);
rows.setTo(new Scalar(0));
```

Comment: Its is better than my 1st way of doing it ^^